# Cannot get a certain Image from a URL Java

Tags: java, android, image, httpurlconnection, android-bitmap

I am working on an app in Android Studio that is using images from this URL https://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/img

---

All the images in this directory work except for this one image: https://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/img/buildings.png

The weird thing about this image is that if I save it in the drawable folder, it loads this image just fine. When I run it, the InputStream line throws "java.net.ProtocolException: Too many follow-up requests: 21". This is the only image that I cannot load from the directory. Can someone explain why the InputStream throws a ProtocolException for this image?

Here is the code I am running. Note-this code runs on a new Thread

```
//src is the  bad url as a string
//myBitmap is a Bitmap array
try {
    URL url = new URL(src);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
    myBitmap[0] = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

} catch ( IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: have you given internet permission?

Comment: Use glide to directly set your image from url to imageView

Comment: I gave it internet permission. I will try using glide to see if it works. If anyone can explain why the InputStream has an issue, that would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are using stream connections for Image loading.... you can get better performance and handled such type of connection issues in  [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

If you wan't Bitmap from URL use:

```
GlideApp.with(itemView.getContext())
        .asBitmap()
        .load(imageUrl)  //https://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/img/buildings.png
        .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {}
            });
        }
```

Comment: Ok that works, Can you explain why that works compared to the method I used?

Comment: There is one issue when need to keep HttpConnection alive all the time while reading chunk from URL, but if some problem if file then this connection closed before EOF.. If this resolve your problem then this answer must be accepted

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the URL actually had multiple copies of the specific image. So the code would ping all the images until it reached the 21 request cap. The way I fixed it was by adding the param v=7. This specified which of the copies I wanted and now it works. Hope that if anyone else runs into this issue that this kind of solution can solve it.